# Exceptions and sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO loctions VALUES('Hogwarts', 'Scotland'")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO characters VALUES('Albus', 'Dumbledore')")
    conn.commit()

except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print "Oops! This was an operational error. Try again..."

except sqlite3.NameError:
    print "Name Error"

except sqlite3.ValueError:
    print "value error"

except sqlite3.IOError:
    print "IO error"

conn.close()
```

I'm trying to figure out if the above is valid code. That is, can I have multiple exceptions after my "try" clause?

When I ran this by typing 'python filename.py', I saw "Oops! This was an operational error. Try again..." printed in my terminal.

This made sense because I had spelled the name of the first table wrong (loctions instead of locations), so it was an Operational Error.

But I'm confused about how to force a Name Error or a Value Error.

Also, when I commented out the "except sqllite3.OperationalError" clause, I got this error in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqle.py", line 14, in <module>
    except sqlite3.NameError:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NameError'
```

Is this saying that there's no such thing as sqlite3.NameError? Yet sqlite3.OperationalError is a thing.

How do I discover what types of errors there are?

Answer (score 9):

[`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError), [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError), [`IOError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError) are [builtin exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions). Don't qualify them with `sqlite3.`:

```
...
except NameError:
    print "Name Error"
except ValueError:
    print "value error"
except IOError:
    print "IO error"
```

---

To see which exceptions are defined in the module (using the property that exceptions are subclass of the `Exception` class):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> [name for name, value in vars(sqlite3).items()
     if inspect.isclass(value) and issubclass(value, Exception)]
['Warning', 'InternalError', 'ProgrammingError', ..., 'OperationalError']
```

Or consult [the module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: This is very helpful with any other package (e.g. peewee), too. Thank you.